# How do I make my container port accesible outside container? ECS - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to get a Docker container running in ECS as a task.  I have created a basic `express` app that is listening on port 3000.  Here is my AWS setup.  I have a ECS cluster with one task.

[image]

I have a container in my AWS repository, which is running as a task in this cluster.

```
{
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::035892600013:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/first-run-task-definition",
          "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": [],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 3000
        }
      ],
      "command": [],
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "image": "035892600013.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test-express:latest",
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": [],
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "test-express"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "512",
  "taskRoleArn": null,
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:035892600013:task-definition/first-run-task-definition:5",
  "family": "first-run-task-definition",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    ...
  ],
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "256",
  "revision": 5,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "volumes": []
}
```

From the JSON, you can see that the container is listening on port 3000, but I can't access the app at `url:3000`.  It just spins.  What else am I missing?

I have tried to curl the application and I get nothing.  The curl just sits waiting for a response.  I did verify the application was running in the container.  Here are the logs:

[image]

Comment: first thing: u run a task not service, ur image show 0 services, 2nd thing: check security port, 3rd thing: check ur node application accesible over host curl localhost:3000, 4th: check is ur node application running inside container